# What should be the default value for missing ordinal variable

Tags: linear-regression, data-cleaning, data-science-model

I want to rerank items based on shipping timelines. But I get shipping info from upstream service only when it is less than 4 days. We don't show user when the shipping timeline is more than 4 days. I get shipping info only when the shipping info is less than 4 days.

I am building a linear model based on shipping timeline and relevancy score (continuous variable). What should be the default value when I do not get shipping info for items with high shipping time?